# How to know the V4L2 camera's exposure time in ms?

Tags: camera, v4l

with `v4l2-ctl`, one can know camera-parameters with following:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d2 --list-ctrls
                 brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
                   contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=31 step=1 default=16 value=16
                      gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=0 max=127 step=1 default=64 value=64
                       gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=1 max=33 step=1 default=0 value=33
       power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=2 (60 Hz)
                  sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=1 value=1
              exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=1 (Manual Mode)
          exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=1 max=1856 step=1 default=2500 value=2500
```

I understand last one `exposure_absolute` is the exposure, but I'm not sure whether this is **always in ms**. Or some other unit (perhaps specific for each cam) that has to be converted to ms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: It's **not** always in ms

It goes down to each firmware implementation, there is no standard. Each camera has its own way of handling the provided value, so you need to check the documentation for each device that you intend to use